# How can I get started with developing apps for Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

I am interested in trying the new Ubuntu for phones OS development. (I am not an Ubuntu developer, I am new to Ubuntu. Impressed by the Ubuntu Touch preview, I got interested in learning how to develop for it).

Where can I start with it? I can't find any guidance on the Ubuntu site.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These links should get you started:

- **Reference:** [Welcome to Ubuntu apps development!](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/apps/)
- **Sample App:** [Tutorials | Ubuntu Developer](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/apps/qml/tutorials/building-your-first-qml-app/)

**How to run the app:**
Once you get all of the SDK installed, you can connect your device via USB, QtCreator will be able to detect it, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> to run it on the device.
**Courtesy:** mhall119

Comment: hehe, but how do you run that app on a device then? :)

Comment: Once you get all of the SDK installed, you can connect your device via USB, QtCreator will be able to detect it, then press Ctrl+F12 to run it on the device.

Comment: @mhall119, Thanks for the information. Have added it to the answer.

Comment: which language is used for developing apps, `QML` or `HTML 5` ??

Comment: @Krunal, `QML` is used to develop the UI component, the actual application(scripting) is done through `JS`. You can find sample code by referring the sample app link posted above.

Comment: The links are broken!  Mind updating them ?

Comment: @PamioSolanky, thanks for pointing it out. I have updated it now. One could always edit the answer and provide with the correct link. :)

Comment: The links are broken again.

Answer (score 4):

There is a 34 part [QML Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLB22HyVdO1GkLFrvRi5vIo5XcWS0EflxD) series by Joseph Mills on YouTube. You can download the tutorials using youtube-dl, which is a terminal app that you can install from the default Ubuntu repositories.