# Ubuntu Apps Forums

Tags: ubuntu-sdk, ubuntu-forums

Is there any dedicated forum to discuss about Ubuntu touch for developing mobile applications using QML.

Is there any perfect documentation regarding using QML of Ubuntu touch apps development.
Please share the links.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get started with developing apps for Ubuntu Touch?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/239490/how-can-i-get-started-with-developing-apps-for-ubuntu-touch)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Developer is probably the best place to start. Click on the [Apps](http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/) tab to get to a walkthrough of developing apps for Ubuntu touch. If you click on the [Community](http://developer.ubuntu.com/community/) tab you'll find a bunch of ways to get in touch with the developer community.