# What is the best way to start developing ubuntu touch apps?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, programming

I'm a starting programmer and I can write c++ programs (nothing more or less). I want to get started with writing Ubuntu touch apps, but I have no idea were to start. Should I just jump into it, or should I first learn Java or something like that?

Thanks in advance!
Jorik

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get started with developing apps for Ubuntu Touch?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/239490/how-can-i-get-started-with-developing-apps-for-ubuntu-touch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that your question is subjective. Therefore this answer is subjective to me.

## Level #1

Get yourself familiarized with QML.
Resources:

- [Watch Joseph's QML Video Training](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y4utTBcSjdM&list=PLxONAPqCQiZfYP8tICOh4a8Z0XOHu9tu6)
- [Download the Qt5 Cadaques QML book](http://qmlbook.org/qt5_cadaques.pdf)

---

## Level #1.5

At this level, you are ready to make a small application. You can get started with Ubuntu Development. Install the Ubuntu SDK , go though design guidelines and make a small application from QML or HTML5:

- [Official Ubuntu Developer Tutorials](http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/sdk/tutorials/)

Learn how to publish your application to the Click App Store from [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h1anchaDI-E).

---

## Level #2

Just knowing QML is not always enough. It's time to learn QT along with C++
Resources:

- [C++ GUI Programming with QT Book](http://qt-project.org/books/view/c_gui_programming_with_qt_4_2nd_edition_the_official_c_qt_book)
- [An Introduction to Design Patterns in C++ with Qt 4](https://qt-project.org/books/view/an_introduction_to_design_patterns_in_c_with_qt_4)

Feel free to checkout [other books on QT/C++/QML](https://qt-project.org/books/)

Answer (score 1):

You can develop Ubuntu Touch apps in either **QML** or **HTML5** which are both very easy to learn.

To get started I would suggest going to these links:

1. [HTML5 App Tutorial](http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/html-5/tutorial/)
2. [Ubuntu Touch App Design Guide](http://design.ubuntu.com/apps)
3. [API Docs](http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/html-5/api/)

You will also need to install the Ubuntu Touch SDK in order to run the samples.

**To install the Ubuntu SDK on 12.04 and higher:**

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk`

Also, [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/239490/how-can-i-get-started-with-developing-apps-for-ubuntu-touch?rq=1) is a link to a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

[Ubuntu developer](http://developer.ubuntu.com/) gives you a start with many tutorials and recources.

Comment: Don't know why my answer is downvoted. @Jorik asks for a start in developing ubuntu touch apps. developer.ubuntu.com is a good starting point for that. Or am i wrong?